# makefile-run processes not in 'jobs' list

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why is it that if I run a program through a makefile, it is does not show up in the `jobs` list, but if I run the command directly from the commandline, it does?

```
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$ python3 coin/coin.py &
[1903] python3 coin/coin.py &
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$ Coin Price Indicator v0.9.3 running!
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$ make
python3 coin/coin.py &
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$ Coin Price Indicator v0.9.3 running!
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$ 
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$ jobs
#:~/code/coinprice-indicator$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. The purpose of `jobs` isn't to show *all* background processes; it only lists those "jobs" which are currently *owned by your shell* and can be controlled by it.

(That is, in an interactive shell, the `&` operator actually adds them to the shell's in-memory job list. But since `make` starts a *new* subshell process for each recipe command, the job information does not automagically propagate upwards – it just gets lost.)